# Using jQuery to close a div and reopen it around an element

Tags: jquery

My HTML looks like this:

```
<div class='background'>
    <div class='item' id='item1'>... </div>
    <div class='item' id='item2'>... </div>
    <div class='item' id='item3'>... </div>
    ... (more 'item's follow)
</div> <!-- background>
```

What I've been trying to accomplish, using jQuery, is to close the `background` div before `item2`, then reopen it again afterwards. Like this:

```
$('#item2').before('</div>');
$('#item2').after('<div class="background">');
```

But jQuery perversely insists on resolving this to:

```
<div class='background'>
    <div class='item' id='item1'>... </div>
    <div class="background"></div>
    <div class='item' id='item2'>... </div>
    <div class='item' id='item3'>... </div>
    ...
</div> <!-- background>
```

which is, obviously, useless.

In increasing desperation, I've tried using the `.html()` method to force the `</div>... <div>` tags to appear. No use: jQuery simply can't believe I want to insert that markup. (This tortured syntax:

```
var oldc = $('#item2').html();
var newc = '</div></div>'+oldc+'<div class="background"><div>';
$('#item2').html(newc);
```

resolves to:

```
<div class="item" id="item2">...
<div class="background"><div></div></div>
</div>
```

(as viewed in Firebug).)

Is there a simple way to resolve this using jQuery, or am I being fundamentally misguided?

To clarify: what I want to end up with is this:

```
<div class='background'>
    <div class='item' id='item1'>... </div>
</div>
    <div class='item' id='item2'>... </div>
<div class="background">
    <div class='item' id='item3'>... </div>
    ... (more 'item's follow)
</div> <!-- background>
```

Comment: Unless I'm reading it wrong it really looks like you are putting a lot of your closing tags BEFORE the opening.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you are trying to accomplish but how about hiding all the items after item2, then showing them after.

Comment: @Jared: No, he wants it to be `</div><div class="background">`.

Comment: Jared: yep, that's the point. I'm trying to close a <div> that's already open, before I open a new one.

Comment: **Mike K** you're overthinking it. Create elements and `append` or `wrap` but what you want to do just doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't just add close tags like that with DOM manipulation.  You can create the new div you want, append it after the existing one and then move some DOM elements from the original background div to the new background div.  You could do that with this code:

```
var newContainer = $("<div class='background'></div>");
$(".background").after(newContainer);
$("#item2").nextAll().appendTo(newContainer);
```

This creates the new background div, places it after the current background div, then gets all siblings after `#item2` and moves them to the new background div.

Working Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/G3uyA/

---

OK, based on your clarification, this code will do the same as the above, but also pull item2 out to be at the same level as the background:

```
var origContainer = $(".background");
var target = $("#item2");
$("<div class='background'></div>").insertAfter(origContainer).append(target.nextAll());
target.insertAfter(origContainer);
```

Working Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/7Dsqw/

Comment: Thanks, that's *almost* it... but not quite. I want to exclude item2 from the background entirely, starting the new background div for item3.

Comment: @MikeK - You mean you want `#item2` to be outside both background containers?  Why didn't you just show the HTML of the desired result in your question?

Comment: @MikeK: Are you able to modify the existing HTML? Or is that out of your control?

Comment: @jfriend00: correct. Sorry, inexperience. I've added what I hope is a clarification to the original question.

Comment: @MikeK - new example added to my answer that also pulls `#item2` out to the same level as the background containers.

Comment: @jfriend00: Thank you, that also works. I'm going with Purmou's answer on this, using 'wrapAll' with 'prevAll' and 'nextAll'. Seems elegant.

Comment: @MikeK - your choice, not sure why you think his is more elegant as it's more steps/function calls.

Comment: There's a lot I could say about the "elegance" of your code. ;)

Answer (score 1):

I think the most efficient way to do this would be to not have these elements contained in the `.background` div by default.

Then, target all elements that come after `#item1` and use `wrapAll()` to wrap them with `.background`:

```
$("#item1").nextAll().wrapAll( $("<div>").addClass("background") );
```

Then target `#item1` and use `wrap()` to wrap it in a second `.background` element:

```
$("#item1").wrap( $("<div>").addClass("background") );
```

You can even chain them:

```
$("#item1")
    .nextAll()
    .wrapAll( $("<div>").addClass("background") )
    .end()
    .wrap( $("<div>").addClass("background") );
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/purmou/2GEpB/1/).

The reason we wrap the ones after `#item1` first is because once `#item1` is wrapped, using `nextAll()` wouldn't give us anything since the rest of the elements would no longer be its siblings.

---

**EDIT:** After your clarification, I modified the above example slightly to not include `#item2` in the `nextAll()`. This way, `#item1` will be placed in its own `.background` element and anything after `#item2` the same. `#item2` will not be affected:

```
$("#item1")
    .nextAll(":not(#item2)")
    .wrapAll( $("<div>").addClass("background") )
    .end()
    .wrap( $("<div>").addClass("background") );
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/purmou/2GEpB/2/).

---

And finally, if you're not actually able to remove the original `.background` from the existing HTML, you can use `unwrap()` to remove the parent but leave all the children:

```
$("#item1")
    .unwrap()
    .nextAll(":not(#item2)")
    .wrapAll( $("<div>").addClass("background") )
    .end()
    .wrap( $("<div>").addClass("background") );
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/purmou/2GEpB/3/).